# Writing from Spark Data Frame to Snowflake named stage

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I am new to snowflake and very naive about spark.
Is there any reference or good example how data is written from spark data frame to named stage in snowflake.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3):

Examples are provided in our API reference, you can read more [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowpark/reference/scala/com/snowflake/snowpark/DataFrameWriter.html)

A quick example of writing a DataFrame to Snowflake:

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("T")
```

The stage is used in between but the target is a table.

Comment: Thanks Sergiu. We have written to using table stage but was looking for reference how to write using snowflake stage file system. As writing to the  file-system will be faster and it will faster for spark to read from . Is there any reference for that or example

Comment: I dont see any specific "snowflake stage file system".Snowflake have different stages like internal , user and table stage which are related to internal stage. You can refer :https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-stage.html

Comment: HI Anand , I meant named stage by sf stage file system

Comment: Hi @Koushur, that is not the purpose of the Stage, to be used instead of the target table. Yes, you can upload files to stage and read a DataFrame out of them, but in the end it's still a table where the data has to land.